# Accessing a C struct from RubyMotion

Tags: c, ruby, pointers, struct, rubymotion

I'm trying to use the giflib C library in RubyMotion. It compiles fine in the vendor folder. But I'm still unsure about C struct access in Ruby:

```
error = Pointer.new(:int)
pointer = DGifOpenFileName("foobar.gif", error) # returns (GifFileType *)
```

The C struct:

```
typedef struct GifFileType {
    GifWord SWidth, SHeight;
    // ...
    ColorMapObject *SColorMap;
    // ...
} GifFileType;
```

Accessing the Ruby Pointer generates a runtime error:

```
puts pointer.value # => Can't find pointer description for type `{ColorMapObject}'
```

What am I doing wrong?

(Here are the complete [gif_lib.h](https://gist.github.com/otagi/293c6a65d3d4af9b8756#file-gif_lib-h) and the generated [giflib.bridgesupport](https://gist.github.com/otagi/293c6a65d3d4af9b8756#file-giflib-bridgesupport).)

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing seems like it should work. I'd file a report with `motion support`.

The [RubyMotion Runtime Guide](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/runtime/#_structures) indicates the following:

> C structures are mapped to classes in RubyMotion. Structures can be created in Ruby and passed to APIs expecting C structures. Similarly, APIs returning C structures will return an instance of the appropriate structure class.
>   A structure class has an accessor method for each field of the C structure it wraps.
>   As an example, the following piece of code creates a CGPoint structure, sets its x and y fields, then passes it to the drawAtPoint:withFont: method.

```
pt = CGPoint.new
pt.x = 100
pt.y = 200
'Hello'.drawAtPoint(pt, withFont: font)
```

> It is possible to pass the field values directly to the constructor.

```
pt = CGPoint.new(100, 200)
'Hello'.drawAtPoint(pt, withFont: font)
```

> RubyMotion will also accept arrays as a convenience. They must contain the same number and type of objects expected in the structure.

```
'Hello'.drawAtPoint([100, 200], withFont: font)
```